# How to create a password protected zip file on ftp server using php

Tags: php, ftp, zip

I would like to create a password protected zip file on ftp server using php. I have try the code below but it does not work. The code below can work in local but when i put on ftp server it does not work. I have one client.php in local and one server.php in ftp server. I put the code below in server.php.(zipArchive or 7-zip both also can be accepted)

(The code below didn't include create password function. It just to create a zip file only.)

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('Ftp://user.com/new/temp.zip', 
 ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
{
    // Add files to the zip file
    $zip->addFile('Ftp://user.com/new/temp/*');

    // All files are added, so close the zip file.
    $zip->close();
    echo"Create Successful";
}
```

Expected Output:

Password protected zip file create successful.

Actual Output:

No zip file created in ftp server.

Comment: If your code runs on the *"ftp server"*, then that machine is a **local machine** (not **ftp server**) in the context of your code. So just write your ZIP file to a local `temp.zip` file - no `ftp://`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i want to zip the file in ftp server. (I use FileZilla to connect the ftp server.)

Comment: And what? Your question is not about FileZilla, but about PHP.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <?php
> $target_dir = "uploads/";
> $target_file = $target_dir . basename( $_FILES[ "fileToUpload" ][ "name" ] );
>
>
> if ( isset( $_POST[ "submit" ] ) ) {
>
>   if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES[ "fileToUpload" ][ "tmp_name" ], $target_file ) ) {
>       echo "The file " . basename( $_FILES[ "fileToUpload" ][ "name" ] ) . " has been uploaded.";
>   } else {
>       echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
>   }
> }
> ?>
> ```

Here is the code which will create zip file only. I don't know how to achieve the zip encryption using `ZipArchive()` method

You may need to use `setEncryptionName()` method to achieve this

Or head over to the [http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setencryptionname.php](http://php%20documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
<?php 
$zip = new ZipArchive(); $zipFile = __DIR__ . '/output.zip'; if (file_exists($zipFile)) { unlink($zipFile); } $zipStatus = $zip->open($zipFile, ZipArchive::CREATE); if ($zipStatus !== true) { throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Failed to create zip archive. (Status code: %s)', $zipStatus)); } $password = 'top-secret'; if (!$zip->setPassword($password)) { throw new RuntimeException('Set password failed'); } // compress file $fileName = __DIR__ . '/test.pdf'; $baseName = basename($fileName); if (!$zip->addFile($fileName, $baseName)) { throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Add file failed: %s', $fileName)); } // encrypt the file with AES-256 if (!$zip->setEncryptionName($baseName, ZipArchive::EM_AES_256)) { throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Set encryption failed: %s', $baseName)); } $zip->close();
<?php>
```

Comment: Try again but without closing php tags and lmk if it works or nah

Comment: Andrew, thank for your help, i found a solution and my problem was solved.